# How to solve ordinary differential inequations with vector variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Given $a\in\mathcal{R}_+^d$ and $s\in\mathcal{R}^d$,we wanna a function f(.) which maps s to a vector $f=\begin{bmatrix}f(s_1),\cdots,f(s_d)\end{bmatrix}^T$ and satisify the following inequation.

\begin{align}
&\frac{a_k\sum_i f_i-\langle a,f\rangle}{2(\sum_i f_i)^2}f_k''-\frac{a_k\sum_i f_i-\langle a,f\rangle}{(\sum_i f_i)^3}f_k'\ge \sigma^2,k=1,\cdots,d
\end{align}

can we get a closed-form f(.)?